# Errors when building release APK - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

when I try to build release apk for my flutterapp, I'm facing these errors. I don't know what to do with this. Please help me to solve these errors.

Errors:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        
Parameter format not correct -
error: error reading C:\Users\91934\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.lifecycle\lifecycle-common\2.2.0\4ef09a745007778eef83b92f8f23987a8ea59496\lifecycle-common-2.2.0.jar; zip END header not found
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\Connectivity.java:5: error: cannot access io.flutter.plugins.connectivity
package io.flutter.plugins.connectivity;
^
  zip END header not found
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java:26: error: cannot access java.lang
public class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
       ^
  zip END header not found
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
public class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
                                                   ^
  symbol: class BroadcastReceiver
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java:27: error: cannot access EventChannel
    implements EventChannel.StreamHandler {
               ^
  zip END header not found
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
  private Context context;
          ^
  symbol:   class Context
  location: class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
  private Connectivity connectivity;
          ^
  symbol:   class Connectivity
  location: class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java:30: error: package EventChannel does not exist
  private EventChannel.EventSink events;
                      ^
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
  private Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
          ^
  symbol:   class Handler
  location: class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java:32: error: cannot access ConnectivityManager
  private ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback;
          ^
  zip END header not found
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
  public static final String CONNECTIVITY_ACTION = "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE";
                      ^
  symbol:   class String
  location: class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
  public ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver(Context context, Connectivity connectivity) {
                                       ^
  symbol:   class Context
  location: class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
  public ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver(Context context, Connectivity connectivity) {
                                                        ^
  symbol:   class Connectivity
  location: class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
  public void onListen(Object arguments, EventChannel.EventSink events) {
                       ^
  symbol:   class Object
  location: class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java:41: error: package EventChannel does not exist
  public void onListen(Object arguments, EventChannel.EventSink events) {
                                                     ^
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
  public void onCancel(Object arguments) {
                       ^
  symbol:   class Object
  location: class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        ^
  symbol:   class Context
  location: class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                                         ^
  symbol:   class Intent
  location: class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java:81: error: package ConnectivityManager does not exist
  public ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback getNetworkCallback() {
                            ^
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityMethodChannelHandler.java:15: error: cannot access io.flutter.plugins
class ConnectivityMethodChannelHandler implements MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler {
^
  zip END header not found
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityMethodChannelHandler.java:15: error: cannot access MethodChannel
class ConnectivityMethodChannelHandler implements MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler {
                                                  ^
  zip END header not found
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityMethodChannelHandler.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
  private Connectivity connectivity;
          ^
  symbol:   class Connectivity
  location: class ConnectivityMethodChannelHandler
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityMethodChannelHandler.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
  ConnectivityMethodChannelHandler(Connectivity connectivity) {
                                   ^
  symbol:   class Connectivity
  location: class ConnectivityMethodChannelHandler
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityMethodChannelHandler.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
  public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
                           ^
  symbol:   class MethodCall
  location: class ConnectivityMethodChannelHandler
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityMethodChannelHandler.java:29: error: package MethodChannel does not exist
  public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
                                                         ^
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityPlugin.java:15: error: cannot access io.flutter
public class ConnectivityPlugin implements FlutterPlugin {
       ^
  zip END header not found
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityPlugin.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
public class ConnectivityPlugin implements FlutterPlugin {
                                           ^
  symbol: class FlutterPlugin
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityPlugin.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
  private MethodChannel methodChannel;
          ^
  symbol:   class MethodChannel
  location: class ConnectivityPlugin
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityPlugin.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
  private EventChannel eventChannel;
          ^
  symbol:   class EventChannel
  location: class ConnectivityPlugin
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityPlugin.java:22: error: cannot access io
  public static void registerWith(io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar registrar) {
                                  ^
  zip END header not found
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityPlugin.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
  public void onAttachedToEngine(FlutterPluginBinding binding) {
                                 ^
  symbol:   class FlutterPluginBinding
  location: class ConnectivityPlugin
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityPlugin.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
  public void onDetachedFromEngine(FlutterPluginBinding binding) {
                                   ^
  symbol:   class FlutterPluginBinding
  location: class ConnectivityPlugin
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityPlugin.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
  private void setupChannels(BinaryMessenger messenger, Context context) {
                             ^
  symbol:   class BinaryMessenger
  location: class ConnectivityPlugin
C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-3.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityPlugin.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
  private void setupChannels(BinaryMessenger messenger, Context context) {
                                                        ^
  symbol:   class Context
  location: class ConnectivityPlugin
33 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':connectivity:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15m 20s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          953.9s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1
```

'[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1586], locale en-IN)
• Flutter version 2.10.3 at C:\src\flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 7e9793dee1 (3 weeks ago), 2022-03-02 11:23:12 -0600
• Engine revision bd539267b4
• Dart version 2.16.1
• DevTools version 2.9.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
• Android SDK at D:\Sdk
• Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
• ANDROID_HOME = D:\Sdk
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.1)
• Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
• Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.1.32228.430
• Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)

[√] VS Code (version 1.65.2)
• VS Code at C:\Users\91934\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.36.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
• Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1586]
• Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 99.0.4844.82
• Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 99.0.1150.46

[√] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!

```
enter code here'
```

Comment: please do flutter clean first.  then flutter pub get and try to build apk again

Comment: i tried but it wont work

Comment: any other solutions

Comment: please provide logs of flutter doctor -v

Comment: Did you try with --stacktrace or -v?

Comment: i made it by using -v